# Stored procedure successfully backs up database but VBA code reports error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, vba

I have written a stored procedure to backup my SQL Server database, but when I call this from Access VBA it gets picked up by the error handler even though the backup is successful. Stored proc is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spBackupDatabase]
    @full bit,
    @bakFile nvarchar(500) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @filepath nvarchar(250)
    DECLARE @filename nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @backupCommand nvarchar(500)

    /* Get @filepath and @filename and use these to set @bakFile - this bit works fine */

    SET @backupCommand = 
        N'BACKUP ' + CASE @full WHEN 1 THEN N'DATABASE' ELSE N'LOG' END + N' [myDatabase] 
            TO  DISK = N''' + @bakFile + N'''
            WITH NOFORMAT, 
            NOINIT,  
            NAME = N''myDatabase -' + CASE @full WHEN 1 THEN N'Full Database' ELSE N'Database Log' END + N' Backup'', 
            SKIP, 
            NOREWIND, 
            NOUNLOAD,  
            STATS = 10'

    EXEC sp_executesql @backupCommand

END
```

The stored procedure is working and performs the backups correctly, but when I call it from VBA code in Access, for some reason it thinks it is resulting in an error, and the code drops through to my error handler. VBA code is:

```
Private Sub cmdBackup_Click()
On Error GoTo PROC_ERR
    Dim conDB As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmdBackup As New ADODB.Command
    Dim prmRetVal As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim prmFull As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim prmBakFile As ADODB.Parameter

    conDB.ConnectionString = gConnectionString
    conDB.Open

    cmdBackup.ActiveConnection = conDB
    cmdBackup.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmdBackup.CommandText = "spBackupDatabase"
    Set prmRetVal = cmdBackup.CreateParameter("retVal", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
    cmdBackup.Parameters.Append prmRetVal
    Set prmFull = cmdBackup.CreateParameter("Full", adBoolean, adParamInput)
    cmdBackup.Parameters.Append prmFull
    Set prmBakFile = cmdBackup.CreateParameter("BakFile", adBoolean, adParamOutput)
    cmdBackup.Parameters.Append prmBakFile

    Select Case MsgBox("Perform FULL backup (select 'No' for an incremental backup)", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel, "Confirm backup type...")
        Case vbYes
            prmFull = True
        Case vbNo
            prmFull = False
        Case vbCancel
            GoTo PROC_EXIT
    End Select
    cmdBackup.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
    If prmRetVal.Value = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Application parameter 'BackupPath' has not been set. Please contact developer for assistance.", vbExclamation, "Unable to perform backup"
    Else
        MsgBox "Backup successfully created at " & prmBakFile, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Done..."
    End If

PROC_EXIT:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set prmRetVal = Nothing
    Set prmFull = Nothing
    Set prmBakFile = Nothing
    Set cmdBackup = Nothing
    conDB.Close
    Set conDB = Nothing
Exit Sub

PROC_ERR:
    Call ShowError("Form_sfmMaintenance", "cmdBackup_Click", Err.Number, Err.Description)
    Resume PROC_EXIT

End Sub
```

The code drops through to `PROC_ERR` when it hits `cmdBackup.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords` and reports error number -2147217913 along with an error description along the lines of "BACKUP LOG successfully processed 2 pages ..."

Any idea how I can prevent this success message from the server being interpreted as an error by my VBA code while still picking up *real* errors (e.g. if the backup location is not valid)?

Comment: `cmdBackup.CreateParameter("BakFile", adBoolean, adParamOutput)` - shouldn't this be a string parameter?

Comment: When you run the SP in SSMS, what is it's return value? ) zero I guess? and there is some stuff in the message window and no result sets anywhere? Just to make certain I suggest you capture the activity in SQL Profiler and make sure there is  nothing unexpected there.

Comment: @Andre: good spot - I will try correcting that later this evening and see if it makes a difference.
@Nick: because of the error condition the return value isn't getting set. VBA is reporting `prmRetVal.Value` as Empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay, thanks to @Andre and @SMM. The error was a true error for data type mismatch. I corrected the data type of `prmBakFile` and it works like a dream now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a better way to avoid the error in the first place but the simplest way would be to wrap your `Call ShowError` in an if statement that checks for that error number and maybe also for the description to contain "successfully". On my phone so something like `If Not (Err.Number = -2147217913 And Err.Description.Contains("successfully")) Then`
.

**EDIT:** To handle returning to the previous point in the code:

```
PROC_ERR:
If (Err.Number = -2147217913 And Err.Description.Contains("successfully")) Then
    'This error is received on success. Continue.
    Resume Next
Else
    Call ShowError("Form_sfmMaintenance", "cmdBackup_Click", Err.Number, Err.Description)
    Resume PROC_EXIT
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this is that because the `cmdBackup.Execute` statement has caused an error, my `prmRetVal.Value` is not getting set and so I can't use this to deliver meaningful information back from the stored proc to VBA.

Comment: Mmm...unstructured error handling is a long time ago :-) Does the edited code work better? No VS available to test with at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, but the fact that it's dropping through to the error handler at all means that VBA is considering this 'success' message as some sort of error. I did try something along these lines before posting, but the error condition means that `prmRetVal.Value` is showing as Empty rather than having an expected value. I think I possibly need to do something server side to suppress the messages unless there is a real error condition, but I couldn't find how to do that.

Comment: Just did a little research. Did you change the prmBakFile to a string per Andre's suggestion above? -2147217913 seems to be a data type mismatch and that seems like the likely candidate. Also, are you sure that the If statement is setup correctly? Unless your proc has some non-displayed return logic I would think you would want to check for 0 return as success else error (e.g. -1 could be an error). If you haven't used breakpoints it's possible that the mismatch is in the 2nd part of your if where you should have prmBakFile.Value in your concatenation.

Comment: by the way, where do you find the error numbers. I did do a search for -2147217913 but couldn't find anything very specific. If I had known it was a data type mismatch I might have worked the solution out for myself.

Comment: I just did a search on the number and looked at the first few results...remember to use quotes because otherwise the minus will remove those pages from the search results in most browsers. That may not be the actual error anyways...13 is usually a type mismatch if i remember correctly but there is a weird thing where some constant (vbObjectError or something) is subtracted before being raised by an OLE component to differentiate between errors in your code...makes all the standard numbers big negatives.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise the minus sign would mess up my search.